# Vapor: Handle HTTPS requests?

Tags: swift, ubuntu-14.04, vps, vapor

I have a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04) with Apache2, Swift 3.1.1 and Vapor installed. I want to receive client side requests to my Vapor-Built-Service via HTTPS protocol (on port 8443 for example). I didn't find any newbie helper document to do this, so please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found the answer:
1. You need to install Apache or Nginx on your VPS. Here I assume that the reader uses Apache. But for more info on installing Apache server on Ubuntu 14.04 you can take a look at [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04).
2. The next thing you need to do is to make Apache work with SSL (or HTTPS protocol). You can find a complete guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04).
3. Now it's time to set the Apache server as a reverse proxy server. You can find a good guide to do that [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) and [here](https://www.fabriziobrancati.com/posts/how-create-telegram-bot-swift-vapor-ubuntu-macos#step-4-2-use-apache-nginx-as-reverse-proxy). don't forget to put the reverse-proxy-config-code at port 443 related part.

---

Update:
There is also another way which you can configure the Vapor directly. Take a look at [here](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/server.html).